# Carry flag set on signed arithmetic

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
mov ah, -128 
mov bh, 80h 
add ah,bh
```

Why does this code set CF, taking into consideration the fact that the computation doesn't need a carry? Or better, what's the behavior of CF in signed arithmetic and of OF in unsigned?

Comment: the `add` doesn't know if the context is "signed" or "unsigned" and it does not need to know. The adding operation is well defined bit-wise, so the `add` will follow that algorithm with the two bit patterns it received, and set *all* flags as described in the instruction guide, i.e. CF is set when input bit patterns interpreted as unsigned values overflow, and OF/SF is set when the same input bit patterns, but interpreted as signed values, overflow/is-negative, etc... like `1000_0000` (80h) is *both* +128 when *interpreted* as unsigned value, and -128 when *interpreted* as signed 8 bit value.

Comment: the unsigned/signed context is then given by following code, which will pick which flags it will detect and use for further processing, but the `add` itself is identical for both contexts and doesn't need to be aware which one is on mind of programmer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The addition is done as [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), and the result is larger than 8 bit. `0x80 + 0x80 = 0x100` or in binary:

```
   0b10000000
+  0b10000000
-------------
= 0b100000000
```

and thus the result is 0 and the Carry Flag is set.

Don't think of `-128` as a negative number, rather think of it as the positive number (`128`) which has the same bit pattern as the two's compliment of your negative number, then carry out the unsigned addition. (And therefore the carry flag is set.)

Comment: because the first is negative, and to my knowledge -128 + 128 is 0 without any borrowing or carry. I may be wrong, this is why i asked the question...

Answer (score 0):

You could not represent 128 with an signed 8 Bit value:

```
-128 = 0x80
```

So you are calculate:

```
(-128)
+ (-128)
-------
-256   (not a 8 Bit value and overflow to the next Byte -> C is set)
```

And the carry is set.

A 8 Bit signed value is good for the range: -128 ... 127

Comment: Carry doesn't care about signed values, it cares about carry-out from the MSB.  So the relevant point is that `0x100` doesn't fit in an 8-bit register, and that the range of unsigned values is `0..255`.  Your answer reads like an explanation of why OF is also set.

Comment: i add -128 and 128, not -128 and -128

Comment: You cannot add -128 and 128 in an 8 bit register; they won’t both fit. If you treat it as signed, you can add -128 and -128. Or if you treat it as unsigned, you can add 128 and 128. In either case, it overflows.